# How do I create an NSPredicate for a subquery given an existing NSPredicate?

Tags: objective-c, nspredicate

In my app, one Audit has many Findings.

I have a method which returns an NSPredicate which filters findings by search text and type ID:

```
+ (NSPredicate)predicateWithSearchText:(NSString *)searchText typeId:(NSNumber *)typeId;
```

I want to use this predicate to filter an array of Audits according to the properties of their findings.  So, given the output of the first method, I want to create a new predicate equivalent to:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(findings, $x, ????).@count > 0"]
```

...where `????` applies my existing predicate to the audit's findings.

How can I do this without exposing the logic inside `+predicateWithSearchText:typeId:`?

Answer (score 0):

Is something like this what you're looking for?

```
- (void)sampleMethod:(NSPredicate *)predicateWithSearchText {
    NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id object, NSDictionary *bindings) {
        BOOL auditFinding = [self auditFinding:object];
        BOOL predFinding = [predicateWithSearchText evaluateWithObject:object];
        return auditFinding && predFinding;
    }];
}
```

Comment: I'm looking for something with that effect, yes.  Ideally I would like it to be exactly equivalent to writing it as a subquery, so that core data can efficiently write it as a SQL statement.  But if nothing like that turns up after a while I'll mark this as the correct answer.